# Elastic query to show exact match OR other fields if not found

Tags: json, search, elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search

I need some help rewriting my elasticsearch query.

What i need is:

1- to show a single record if there is an exact match on the two fields `verb` and `sessionid.raw` (partial matches are not accepted).

```
"must": [
    { "match" : { "verb" : "login" } },
    { "term"  : { "sessionid.raw" : strSessionID } },
]
```

OR

2- to show the top 5 records (sorted by `_score DESC` and `@timestamp ASC`) that match some other fields, giving a boost if the records are between the specified time range.

```
"must": [
    { "match" : { "verb" : "login" } },
    { "term"  : { "pid" : strPID } },
],
"should": [
    { "match" : { "user.raw" : strUser } },
    { "range" : { "@timestamp" : {
        "from"      : QueryFrom,
        "to"        : QueryTo,
        "format"    : DateFormatElastic,
        "time_zone" : "America/Sao_Paulo",
        "boost"     : 2 }
    } },
]
```

The code below is almost doing what i want.
Right now it boosts `sessionid.raw` to the top if found, but the remaining records are not being discarded.

```
var objQueryy = {
    "fields" : [ "@timestamp", "program", "pid", "sessionid.raw", "user", "frontendip", "frontendname", "_score" ],
    "size"   : ItemsPerPage,
    "sort"   : [ { "_score" : { "order": "desc" } }, { "@timestamp" : { "order" : "asc" } } ],
    "query"  : {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                { "match" : { "verb" : "login" } },
                { "term"  : { "pid" : strPID } },
                { "bool":  {
                    "should": [
                        { "match" : { "user.raw" : strUser } },
                        { "match" : { "sessionid.raw": { "query": strSessionID, "boost" : 3 } } },
                        { "range" : { "@timestamp" : { "from": QueryFrom, "to": QueryTo, "format": DateFormatElastic, "time_zone": "America/Sao_Paulo" } } },
                    ],
                }},
            ],
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: do you want all the three conditions inside `should clause` to match?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 not really. only those inside the `must` clause are mandatory.

Comment: ok, it would be good if you could show us some sample documents that you think should be discarded but they still show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch cannot "prune" your secondary results for you when an exact match is also found.

You would have to implement this discarding functionality on the client side after all results had been returned.

---

You may find the cleanest implementation is to execute your two search strategies separately.  Your search client would:

1. Run the first (exact match) query
2. Run the second (expanded) query *only if no results found*